# Displaying image in oracle report

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I want to add an image from file system in oracle report (By using the formula column on report column condition), the image path I gave is like \10.1.2.50\pics\pic123.jpg

while running the report on design time from my laptop it works fine and displays the image but when I deploy the report on WebLogic server it gives me an error that the file not found. Both design time and server are in the same domain. (If I try to navigate the URL \10.1.2.50\pics\pic123.jpg in the server where WebLogic server is installed the URL also get resolved from there that means the file is accessible there too)

Comment: What are you using to create the report? If you are talking about deploy on weblogic, you are using java. Share us the exact error in the browser console and network tabs

Comment: I am using Oracle reports builder to create a report. To deploy that report I simply convert that report (.FMB) to FMX format and then copy it to a specified folder in the WebLogic server. The user then calls that report from his computer through a URL. If the picture used in the report is on the same server where the WebLogic server is, the user gets the results but another way he gets the error.